# Remove a piece from a string from a big database

Tags: sql

I have a database like this

[image: Database]
and it goes on for like 2.7m more lines.

Is there an SQL condition where I can remove the identifier from the titleurl in the whole column?

Thank you!

Comment: HInt:　replace()

Comment: Permanent or temporarily (for the query)?

Comment: @ChrisHaas permanent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SQL replace() so you can do it something like this

SELECT

```
SELECT REPLACE(titleurl , identifier, '') FROM your_table
```

UPDATE

```
UPDATE your_table SET titleurl = REPLACE(titleurl , identifier, '')
```